# How to make the refresh rate of a VMware guest +120hz?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

I have a ubuntu system, my monitor is 144hz, and i would like to have a +120hz refresh rate inside my WIN10 guest as well, is there any way i can do this? right now the maximum refresh rate inside the guest is 60hz. I have a VMware workstation (V15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you have a monitor with 144hz refresh rate, then you can't set it no more than 60hz.

VMware does not give you a direct access to your graphics card and  you don't get access to all of the features of your physical graphics card. So you can't use very high refresh rate in your VM displays.

VMs are provided virtual hardware, which use physical hardwares and the calls are translated to make the VM being run in them. There are numerous hardware limitations.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not a setting for Refresh Rate since the Video hardware is the VMware Hardware.

You can set the resolution and stretch, but not the refresh rate.

That is just a limitation of the virtual hardware.

Comment: So even other virtualization software like VirtualBox cannot do this correct?

Comment: That is correct. I check all my VMware machines and settings for those machines.  Virtual Box is essentially the same.